# Why is Snappy hanging on any command?

Tags: linux, certbot, snap

Server is AlmaLinux 8.5 (converted from CentOS).

I had been doing some work to add a new web site which included the usual `dnf update` and also installing `php81-php-fpm` and some associated packages. All went well until I tried to set up a new SSL certificate with Certbot.

The `certbot` command simply hangs. There was evidence in the logs that it had successfully run a renew cycle within the previous 24 hours, and the server had been rebooted after the updates (which included a kernel update).

Further investigation revealed that the `snap` command (Certbot having been installed with it) also hangs. Specifically `snap help` works but even `snap version` hangs. I suspect this may be behind the `certbot` hangs. Snappy version is 2.53.4.

I cannot find any Snappy-specific logs and `messages` doesn't show anything obvious. I have also confirmed `snapd.service` is running.

I rebooted the server again and inspected `messages` and these were the `snap` entries. Maybe that last entry relates to the issue?

```
Dec 27 20:31:54 zkarj-alma01 systemd[1]: Starting Socket activation for snappy daemon.
Dec 27 20:31:54 zkarj-alma01 systemd[1]: Started Timer renew for snap application certbot.renew.
Dec 27 20:31:54 zkarj-alma01 systemd[1]: Listening on Socket activation for snappy daemon.
Dec 27 20:32:26 zkarj-alma01 systemd[1787]: Listening on REST API socket for snapd user session agent.
Dec 27 20:34:15 zkarj-alma01 systemd[1]: Started snap.certbot.certbot.210f1e08-0000-45c6-8927-a0252806888f.scope.
Dec 27 20:34:16 zkarj-alma01 snapd[1910]: AppArmor status: apparmor not enabled
Dec 27 20:34:16 zkarj-alma01 snapd[1910]: daemon.go:242: started snapd/2.53.4-1.el8 (series 16; classic; devmode) almalinux/8.5 (amd64) linux/4.18.0-348.7.1.el8_5.x86_.
Dec 27 20:34:16 zkarj-alma01 snapd[1910]: daemon.go:335: adjusting startup timeout by 45s (pessimistic estimate of 30s plus 5s per snap)
Dec 27 20:34:16 zkarj-alma01 dbus-daemon[776]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.timedate1' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.timedate1.service' requested by ':1.71' (uid=0 pid=1910 comm="/usr/libexec/snapd/snapd " label="system_u:system_r:snappy_t:s0")
Dec 27 20:34:25 zkarj-alma01 systemd[1]: snap.certbot.certbot.210f1e08-0000-45c6-8927-a0252806888f.scope: Succeeded.
Dec 27 20:35:01 zkarj-alma01 systemd[1954]: Listening on REST API socket for snapd user session agent.
Dec 27 20:35:12 zkarj-alma01 systemd[1954]: Closed REST API socket for snapd user session agent.
```

Any help or suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Posted this in the Let's Encrypt forum as well, even though it seemed like a Snappy issue. A user there pointed me here:

https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/snapd-unavailable-red-hat-enterprise-linux/28004/2

A version of those steps did cure the problem, though not permanently. I hope the new version currently in testing (2.54.1) will provide a permanent solution.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).